# Only 1 column in .dat, X and Y are constants, how to draw a 3D-plot using Gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

Want to draw a 3D-plot.
X and Y are both from 1-200, namely 200*200, 40000 numbers in .dat, only 1 column.
Do I need to change the data file to the official 3D format, like:

```
1   1     z1
1   2     z2
...
1   200   z200
2   1     z201
2   2     z202
...
2   200   z400
...
...
200 200   z40000
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is represented like so:

```
x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2...
```

then you could use `every` to access only the axis you want to plot. However, a much cleaner way would be to output the data as you mentioned above.

Comment: But mine is z1 z2 z3 ... zn :)

Comment: I've found here a solution while under certain condition
http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/heatmaps.html